# How can i use a value from a form input to match in my database and fetch record/row data to prefill a form?

Tags: php, arrays, json, forms, mysqli

I have a form input named "invoiceidcopy" ...I need to match the value of a this input value to that of the value in my database under the column (invoiceidcopy) and then fetch its associated record/row of form data to prefill my form when i hit the "#submit-id" button.

My form and data base have the following inputs/columns named "invoiceidcopy", "location", "q1", "subcheck".

Below is as far as I've gotten I feel like I'm close if even that.

Much appreciation and Thanks to anyone's help in advance.

**FORM**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/xxx.php">

<input id="invoiceidcopy" name="invoiceidcopy" type="text" value="XXXIDXXX"/>



         <button id="submit-id">Prefill Form</button>


        <input id="location" name="location" required="" type="text">



<input type="radio" id="q1" name="q1" value="4.99" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" id="q1" name="q1" value="7.99" />

        <input id="subcheck" name="subcheck" value="0" type="hidden">
        <input id="subcheck" name="subcheck" value="1" onclick="return false" checked="" type="checkbox">Agree to Terms of Service


    <button id="btn1" type="submit" name="Submit">Submit</button>


</form>




<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
     $(function(){


        $('#submit-id').on('click', function(e){  // Things to do when '#submit-id' button is clicked
            var invoiceidcopy = $('#invoiceidcopy').val(); // Grab user invoiceidcopy from text field
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submit, we are submiting form down with ajax.

             $.ajax({
              url: "/tst/orders2.php",
              data: {


'invoiceidcopy':invoiceidcopy  


               }
            })

.done(function(data) {
data = JSON.parse(data);
$('#location').val(data.location);
$('#q1').val(data.q1);
$('#subcheck').val(data.subcheck);
});
        });
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**/tst/orders2.php**

```
<?php

// Create the connection to the database
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");


// Check if the connection failed
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  die();
}



  if (isset($_GET['invoiceidcopy']))
{
    $invoiceidcopy= $_GET['invoiceidcopy'];

   $query = "SELECT location, q1, subcheck
        FROM seguin_orders
  WHERE invoiceidcopy = '".($invoiceidcopy)."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 echo json_encode($row);
 die(); 
} 


    ?>
```

Comment: which part u have the problem?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, and `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`. You'll need to check for possible errors and debug it if you do get some. You only posted code with no indication of what's not working.

Comment: Use jQuery's Onclick event and fill data in form using AJAX .

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine for the text field and radio/checkbox...
but `.val()` will set the value of the radio/checkbox

To toggle between checked & unchecked ...etc ...you may need to use `.attr()` or `.prop()`  and set `checked` as required as per the pre-filled value

```
$("#q1").attr('checked', true);

$('#subcheck').prop('checked', true);
```